# How can I edit Tomcat VM arguments in STS/Eclipse without the UI ? Eg. using batch file or java program ? Which file holds all these values?

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, tomcat, spring-tool-suite

[image]

I am working on bootstraping the process of workspace setup for new devlopers. Which file contains VM arguments.

Comment: Are the values ultimately stored in a configuration file?

Comment: Try looking for that string in your project configuration file: [.project](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fproject_description_file.html)

Comment: I have tried to look at all the files under 'conf' folder but don't see any specific file where these info. are stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this is stored in a launch configuration. Those launch configurations can be stored in the projects themselves (for example if you want to commit them to a version control system) or they are located in the workspace metadata.

The default setting is the workspace metadata. Take a look at files in: `<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches/`

If you want to change the location to include the launch configs in your projects, go to the "Common" tab in the dialog that you posted above and select "Share file" instead of "Local file".